# How from firefox addon to get the content of iframe the displayed page?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, firefox-addon

For example, i have in firefox an open the following page:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body> text
       <iframe id="wikipedia" src="http://en.wikipedia.org"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

How from my addon to get of wikipedia text displayed in the iframe?

i.e.

```
...
Welcome to Wikipedia,
the free encyclopedia that anyone can edit.
4,462,480 articles in English
...
```

etc.

Comment: i dont know why people down voted you for this. ill give you solution below

Comment: I do not care voting - Very need solving.

Answer (score 0):

this code here opens a new tab in the most recent navigator:browser window and on load it looks for iframes and gets its content/

this solution is better because if iframe is loading, i test to see if its loading if iframe.contentDocument exists or not, this is not the most accurate way to test this, i just can't think of another one right now. **if anyone else reads this please share a better method to see if iframe is loaded or not**

but if the iframe is loading it will wait for the iframe to load than it will log to browser console the html of the iframe

copy paste this to scratchpad, make sure environement is set to "Browser", this is tested and working

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm')
var aDOMWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var newTabBrowser = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(aDOMWindow.gBrowser.loadOneTab('http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocaletimestring', {
    inBackground: false
}));
newTabBrowser.addEventListener('load', function onloadFunc() {
    Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('tab loaded');
    newTabBrowser.removeEventListener('load', arguments.callee, true);
    var doc = newTabBrowser.contentDocument;
    var win = doc.defaultView;
    var iframes = doc.querySelectorAll('iframe');
    Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('number of iframes in this tab = ' + iframes.length);
    [].forEach.call(iframes, function (frm, i) {
        logIframeHtml(frm, i);
    });

}, true);

function logIframeHtml(iframe, i) {

    iframe.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', logIframeHtml, true); //this line removes the event listneer if it had one

    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    if (!iframeDoc) {
        Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('iframe ' + i + ' is not fully loaded yet as it its contentDocument does not exist');
        iframe.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', logIframeHtml, true);
    } else {
        var iframeInnerHtml = iframeDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
        Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('iframe ' + i + ' innerHTML = ' + iframeInnerHtml);
    }
}
```

Comment: iframe on page fully loaded. In the browser i can see it. All I need - to get text that I see in browser.
I'm new in developing add-ons. But I will try to understand your solution. Nevertheless if possible require high performance. opening new tabs and reloaded iframe maybe it slowly
As I understand it - just read the contents of the iframe is impossible even from add-ons?

Comment: ah ok so just the currently open tab? ill post that solution below

Answer (score 0):

solution for just currently loaded tab in most recent navigator:browser and iframe is already loaded

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm')
var aDOMWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var iframes = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.contentDocument.querySelectorAll('iframe');
Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('number of iframes in this tab = ' + iframes.length);
[].forEach.call(iframes, function (frm, i) {
        var iframeInnerHtml = frm.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;
});

function logIframeHtml(iframe, i) {

    iframe.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', logIframeHtml, true); //this line removes the event listneer if it had one

    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    if (!iframeDoc) {
        Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('iframe ' + i + ' is not fully loaded yet as it its contentDocument does not exist');
        iframe.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', logIframeHtml, true);
    } else {
        var iframeInnerHtml = iframeDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
        Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('iframe ' + i + ' innerHTML = ' + iframeInnerHtml);
    }
}
```

this solution here is for the current tab but not trusting if iframe is loaded:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm')
var aDOMWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var iframes = aDOMWindow.gBrowser.contentDocument.querySelectorAll('iframe');
Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('number of iframes in this tab = ' + iframes.length);
[].forEach.call(iframes, function (frm, i) {
    logIframeHtml(frm, i);
});

function logIframeHtml(iframe, i) {

    iframe.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', logIframeHtml, true); //this line removes the event listneer if it had one

    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
    if (!iframeDoc) {
        Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('iframe ' + i + ' is not fully loaded yet as it its contentDocument does not exist');
        iframe.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', logIframeHtml, true);
    } else {
        var iframeInnerHtml = iframeDoc.documentElement.innerHTML;
        Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.console.log('iframe ' + i + ' innerHTML = ' + iframeInnerHtml);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used to use firefox addons builder, but now this service is no longer.

So I have to deal with how to write addon from zero.
before I inserted the script in main.js
And now I do not know where to put your solution.
It would be nice if you could send the finished version.
My mail is:

2014Alexander@mail.ru

Ideally need a button. When it is pressed, the contents of all iframe placed on the clipboard.
I understand that asking the impossible. But if you were so kind to send - it would be wonderful.

Comment: this is the finished version man. do you want a full addon. upload your addon to github or something and tell me where you would like me to place ill gladly place it in there for you.

Comment: Just registered on GitHub. But not figured out how to upload there. so I sent you a letter with zip archive my addon.
to noitidart@gmail.com.

Comment: I updated the page all day - waiting for your answer :)

Comment: to noitidart@gmail.com i send letter with attached files.
maybe you have Skype? But probably easier if you sent a full work addon to my mail: 2014alexander@mail.ru

Comment: oh ur mail went to my spam box i see it now

Comment: I'm assuming this is still the best solution? I have tried to do this with a page-mod worker and doing a worker.tab.attach contentscript and dumping document.body.innerHTML and I can see the iframe tags, but the content doesn't get dumped with it.

Comment: @Derek using page-mod is the best way to do it. The above is not e10s friendly. If you want to follow the above method you have to use the e10s frinedly way of framescripts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFrameScriptLoader#loadFrameScript%28%29

Comment: Well when I am using page-mod, I can't actually seem to get the contents of the iframe as it is rendered on the page. Are you saying I would then have to just hit the source of the iframe from my add-on directly to see what it's contents are?

Comment: @Derek what do you mean contents? The innerHTML? Try `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: Yes, what I am saying is that document.body.innerHTML in this case does not return the contents of the iframe. It returns the `<iframe></iframe>` tags, but not the contents between the tags.